# Structures in functions

Tags: c

I am new to structures and I have a task to first make a structure "Points" that holds x and y (DONE) then make a function `printPoint()` that would print the points made in main (DONE) and then I must make a function `Point createPoint(double x, double y)` that would create a Point type structure, fill it in with coordinates and return it, so the p1 and p2 variables in main would be made with `createPoint()`, how do I exactly do that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
} Point;

void printPoint(Point p1, Point p2) {
    printf("%d %d\n%d %d", p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y);
}

Point createPoint(double x, double y) {
    ?
}

int main()
{
    Point p1 = {2.0, -3.0};
    Point p2 = {-4.0, 5.0};
    printPoint(p1, p2);
}
```

Comment: How are you doing it in main()? Can you use that pattern in createPoint?

Comment: The Point structure contains "int" but you initialize it with floats in the main().

Comment: @Norbertas Why does the function  Point createPoint(double x, double y) have arguments of the type double instead of the type int?

Comment: I think it just should be like Point p1 = createPoint(2.0, -3.0); in main and the same to p2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as simple as that:

```
Point createPoint(double x, double y) {
  Point point = {x, y};
  return point;
}
...
printPoint(createPoint(1,2), createPoint(3,4));
...
```

But `double` should probably be `int` here. Or maybe `struct Point` should contain `double` fields rather than `int` fields. Only you know the answer.